# Angular4 always require Browsers Cache Clean

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a web application in production environment. The users are using it every day, when I publish an update and a user comes back to the web application he/she views the old version of the web application. He needs to refresh the browser to load the new version. How can I solve this problem? I cannot tell hundreds of users to refresh the page every time I publish an update (3-4 times a week).
I have used following to build my front end application : Angular4 with angular-cli

Comment: do you use webpack for publishing?

Comment: are you using the --target=production flag when using ng build? This will add a cache busting string to the end of the bundle files

Comment: I will try this. In addition I have used set Interval method to invoke a particular service. I have setup this into ngOnInit() method of a components. But problem is it is only working when i use F12 browser button.

Comment: if you are using angular cli and when you create production build file it automatically creates bundle files with different names every time.you just need to put some meta tag in index.html so you browser not cache uyour index.html file.your problem is fixed.

Comment: Is this command "--target=production"   works for you @Ashish chauhan

Answer (score 18):

The best way to clean browser cache would be to use hashing at build time. command to add hashing in angular cli app is

```
ng build --prod --output-hashing=all
```

It will generate build file with different name each time we build.

Just in case you are not using angular cli you can declare you component this way to cache busting

```
@Component({
  selector: 'some-component',
  templateUrl: `./app/component/stuff/component.html?v=${new Date().getTime()}`,
  styleUrls: [`./app/component/stuff/component.css?v=${new Date().getTime()}`]
})
```

Also we can set cache expire time in our nginx server. run this command

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

to  edit config file & add these line to set cache settings

```
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
  expires 3d;
}
```

this will set expire time to 3 days. so the browser will automatically delete all stored cache of your web app & download fresh copy.

> jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js <--  configuration will cache jpg/jpeg/png/gif/ico images as well as javascript

Comment: Sorry to ask, do I have to do both operations (build and server configuration) or just one of them?

Comment: @LunaticJape just one of them

Comment: I tried  `build --out-hashing=all` but I still have to use refresh without cache to display changes on the website. Does this work in docker container?

Comment: @LunaticJape well I have never used docker. but even after using ng build command you have to refresh your web app or reopen your web app to see the latest changes. there is no direct way to see you change in real time.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the [angular-cli docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build), there are 2 ways of enabling cache busting.

1. --prod or --target=production will set a number of flags, including --output-hashing=all which is what triggers the cache-busting
2. You can also set --output-hashing itself on the command line with one of its possible values of [none|all|media|bundles]. This is useful for testing/staging builds.

Comment: But, How to cache-busting for the 'Index.html' file ?

Comment: @Karthikvenkat86 you don't cache-bust the index file, browsers won't generally cache HTML.

Comment: If you're hitting reload then the index file should be requested with Max-Age: 0 so generally it should be an issue

Comment: `--output-hashing` option has gone and `--prod` takes forever (35 seconds vs 8 for just aot)! Wish there was a way to just an option to add a random id.

Answer (score 1):

For npm use the following below : Angular 7 +

```
RUN npm run build -- --prod --output-hashing=all
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also handy if you are having cache issues using

```sh
ng build --watch
```

Change your command to:

```sh
ng build --watch --output-hashing=all
```

This will cache bust all your js by hashing the js names.